# How to check the same condition in textField and textView at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uitextview

I've got 2 textFields and 1 textView, all these fields have a content, comes from `previousViewController`, I need to enable or disenable the rightBarButtonItem according to user's changes in these fields, if new content is different from current content, which comes from `previousViewController`. How to check textFields and textView at the same time? Now I have (conditions sometimes contradict each other)

in viewDidLoad:

```
loginTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

displayNameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

then:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if displayNameTextField.text != currentDisplayName || loginTextField.text != currentUsername {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    }

}

func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if aboutTextView.text == currentAbout {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "conditions sometimes contradict each other"? Can you describe how your current code does not work?

Comment: Sometimes if works 1 condition doesn't work 2nd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not extracting it to the function and check it there like this:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    validateFields()
}

func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    validateFields()
}

func validateFields() {
    if aboutTextView.text == currentAbout || displayNameTextField.text == currentDisplayName || loginTextField.text == currentUsername {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but need to change == to != and swap false/true